# How To Change the name of different install partitions on USB drive

Tags: install, partition, macos

I seached the whole stack exchange & the inter webs about how to change the names of this install partitions of my USB harddrives.
I want them called
i10.5
i10.6
i10.7
i10.8
i10.9

Anyone the Magic way?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo bless --folder /Volumes/yourdisk -label "Title here"
```

`bless` is the command to set startup disk options.
`--folder` specifies the disk and `-label` assigns it a label.

Comment: One line answers without explanation are highly discouraged.

Comment: @Max I thought the command was self explanatory—edited anyway

Comment: OK. But how can bless be self explanatory when used outside a church?